# Dynamic Cloudpages across Multi-org BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm building a solution that I'm not sure will end up working for a couple reasons.

Background: Multi-Org set up with multiple Sales Cloud and/or Service Cloud orgs, as well as Dynamics CRM.

Building 1 dynamic form that will be housed on websites via iFrame that will submit data to one of each of those MC BU orgs and CRM orgs (in addition to GoToMeeting).

Problem: The problem is that with so many places this one form has to push data to, AMPscript won't be a viable solution. Am I right to believe this is either not possible and/or this will have to be achieved if it is possible via Javascript.

My testing hasn't given me concrete answers and I just want to confirm before I try building out more.

Comment: Sounds like Web to lead forms would be a better solution - at least for the Salesforce part, not sure how to handle Dynamics: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thank you, web to lead can handle multi-orgs on one landing page? haven't considered that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible but you'd have to get into the API - which is technically feasible with AMPScript, e.g. HTTPPOST2 method - but you'd probably want to use SSJS due to its better errorhandling (basically try / catch)

Due to the general shortcomings of iFrames, I would also consider keeping the forms natively built into the various pages, but making them talk to a common REST endpoint that also handles the distribution over your different orgs and returns e.g. a JSON response to the pages calling them.

You can use a Cloudpage for that endpoint, and here is a terrific article about this to get you started on it:
http://www.devsutd.com/writing-a-rest-service-using-cloud-pages/

Comment: thank you i will dive into this